# how to check sim cards every time choosing one of the sim cards before dialing ussd code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Hello Stack overflow community

I am building an app that using for dialing Unstructured Supplementary Service Data for paid services in Somalia. for example my mobile have 2 sim cards (sim1: Telesom) and (Sim2: Somtel), So what i want to do is: how to check sim cards every time i choose one of the sim cards before dialing ussd code when the box (Make calls with) appear.

If I choose sim1, I want to check if that sim card is (Telesom or Somtel)?

```
 if(selectedMoney.value == "SLSH") {
   val Total = myViewModel.mobile.toInt()
   val dialedNum = "*220*0$Total*${myViewModel.money}%23"

   val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)

   callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$dialedNum")


   // here checking sim card every time i choose one of them
   if(simcard1 == "Telesom"){
       ContextCompat.startActivity(context, callIntent, null)
   }
                 
 }
```